# NIM game against PC beginner

Tags: c++, c

My professor gave me a asignment to write a 16 matches Nim game.

One part of a task is to make PC to make moves as well. So, I tried to solve the problem by using SRAND but PC picked the same row and the same amount of sticks. What is more, PC also takes emty rows wich and hits the wall when he takes the zero massive.

So, thats is what I hve already done. Any  thoughts?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define row 4

int main()
{

    int theChecker = 1, sticks[row] = {1,3,5,7}, stickSum, i, choiceRow, choiceStick, pcRow, pcStick;
    char answer;
    do
    {
        printf("\n\n\t  ************ \n");
        printf("\t *THE NIM GAME* \n");
        printf("\t  ************ \n\n");

        stickSum = sticks[0] + sticks[1] + sticks[2] + sticks[3];

        while(stickSum > 0)
        {
            printf("\nStick log:\n");
            for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
                printf("Row %d: %d\n", i+1, sticks[i]);
            printf("\n");

            if(theChecker == 1)
            {
                printf("Choose a row: ");
                scanf("%d", &choiceRow);
                printf("Choose a sick: ");
                scanf("%d", &choiceStick);
                while((choiceRow <= 0) || (choiceRow > 4) || (sticks[choiceRow - 1] < choiceStick) || (choiceStick == 0))
                {
                    printf("\n\t    !!!ERROR!!!\n\tInvalid row or stick\n\nCheck stick log above\n\n");
                    printf("Choose a row: ");
                    scanf("%d", &choiceRow);
                    printf("Choose a sick: ");
                    scanf("%d", &choiceStick);
                }
                sticks[choiceRow-1] -= choiceStick;
                stickSum -= choiceStick;
            }
            else    //pc move starts-------------------------------------------
            {
                while(((pcRow <= 0) || (pcRow > 4)) && sticks[choiceRow - 1] == 0)
                {
                    time_t seconds;
                    seconds = 0;
                    time(&seconds);
                    srand((unsigned int)seconds);
                    pcRow = rand() % 4;
                }
                printf("PC ROW: %d\n", pcRow);

                while((sticks[pcRow - 1] < pcStick) || (pcStick == 0))
                {
                    time_t seconds2;
                    seconds2 = 0;
                    time(&seconds2);
                    srand((unsigned int)seconds2);
                    pcStick = rand() % 16;
                }
                printf("PC STICK: %d\n\n", pcStick);


                sticks[pcRow-1] -= pcStick;
                stickSum -= pcStick;
            }

            if((theChecker == 1) && (stickSum == 0))
                printf("\n\n!!!GAME OVER!!! You took the last stick!!!\n\n");
            else if((theChecker == 2) && (stickSum == 0))
                printf("\n\n!!!CONGRATS!!! You won!!!\n\n");
            theChecker++;
            if(theChecker == 3)
                theChecker -= 2;
        }

        printf("\nPress r to restart the game or any key to end the game: ");
        scanf("%c", &answer);
        printf("\n");
    }
    while(answer == 'r');
    return 0;`enter code here`
}
```

Comment: If you expect code review, next time consider asking at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: the variables: pcrow and pcstick are being used before being initialized.  Suggest setting them to some known/invalid values at the point in the code where they are declared

Comment: this line, in your question: 'emty rows wich and hits the wall when he takes the zero massive.' has me totally confused.  Please edit so it iis meaningful

Comment: regarding these 4 lines: time_t seconds;
                    seconds = 0;
                    time(&seconds);
                    srand((unsigned int)seconds);  1) they should be at the very beginning of the program.  2) reduce to: 'srand(time(NULL));'

Comment: the code should always check the returned value from scanf() to assure the input/conversion operation was successful

Comment: the posted code is NOT C++, so that tag should be removed

Comment: Perhaps I missed something, however, what is the question? Does something go wrong when the code is run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call `srand()` more than once, it's used to initialize the random *seed*, which you are always initializing to the same value, the internal state gets reset over and over, always producing the same pseudo-random values.

I say that you always pass the same *seed*, because `time()` has seconds resolution, and in once second, the whole game was played and terminated.

You just need a call to `srand()` at the beginning of the program to prevent the program from choosing the same values across runs of the program, not in the same *run*.